# Run shell command in safe mode - php

Tags: php, shell, shell-exec

I want to execute shell commands on my server. I'm using shell_exec() for that purpose. Problem is with safe mode turned on it gives error:

```
PHP Warning:  shell_exec(): Cannot execute using backquotes in Safe Mode
```

Also **i do not want to turn off safe mode**. Is there anyway to execute this with safe mode or any other command for same purpose?

Comment: What is the string that you're passing to `shell_exec()`?

Comment: im trying to run mysql command

Comment: @singhshivam There shouldn't be any reason to run mysql commands through the command line. You can do everything you need to do using MySQLi or PDO, as long as you have the right permissions.

Comment: @EdCottrell i have to dump sql in mysql. I cannot find any MySQLi command for that. Thats y i was using shell_exec() in first place.

Comment: If you really want to run in Safe Mode, you'll have to write your own routine for that. List all the tables, views, stored programs, etc., and dump them all out, one at a time, using regular SQL statements.

Answer (score 2):

[**Safe Mode disables `shell_exec()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.functions.php):

> shell_exec() (functional equivalent of backticks)  This function is disabled when PHP is running in safe mode.

The whole point of Safe Mode is to prevent shell-level execution from within a PHP script. So, no, there's no way around it, unless you write your own PHP extension.

Also, be aware that [Safe Mode is DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0](https://www.php.net/features.safe-mode).

Comment: yeah i read that. also that safe mode is deprecated from the latest php versions. But still i was wondering is there any possibility for this?
really appreciate your help!

Comment: See my edit. No, there's no way around it; the point of Safe Mode is to prevent exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Your requirement is to dump mysql and there is no MySQLi library for that. So what you can do is, create a PHP extension that does mysqldump (you can use the `system` function in C), install the extension and call it from PHP as a function.

An example of how to create a PHP extension is here: http://devzone.zend.com/303/extension-writing-part-i-introduction-to-php-and-zend/

Comment: I was avoiding that in the beginning but i guess its the only option now. Thanks for your advice! :)